# webscrape javascript output c# winform

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, web-scraping

is it possible to webscrape an website with an output of a javascript document.write?? I know how to use webclient and scrape anything I would like to scrape what i would need, but I'm trying to scrape a specific output from a javascript document.write. Is that possible I have been googling around and ofcourse also tried some things but I can not get it working. I'm working with visual studio 2010 c# programming.

Is there someone willing to help me with this. Below is my code that works normal on regular scraping but not with what I would like to scrape:

```
private string GetURL()
    {
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {               
            return wc.DownloadString("url_to_scrape");
        }
    }


var scrape = GetURL.Between("something", "new");
```

So this is how I would scrape something that I would like to use, but it does not work with a document.write from javascript.

All help would be great;)

Comment: you can use a webbrowser control to load the page, then parse the text on the rendered page.

Comment: Ok I can load it using the webbrowser control the outcome is the javascript, but I don't know how to parse the output to a textbox? Could you show me an example code of this? Regards dennis